# Matplotlib: How to add two custom colorbars to an image map

Tags: python, matplotlib

The setup...
I have a set of paired values (z,w) that are mapped over 2D space (i.e. f(x,y) = (z,w)) that I'm making an image map from. My preferred way of doing this is where the rgb color at each point is given as:
(r,g,b) = (z'*w', z'*(1-w'), z'),
z' and w' being normalized to be between 0 and 1 (for colormapping purposes).
In this way the z value effectively determines the lightness of the point and the w value determines the red-blue hue.

Here's the issue...
I can make this image map but the colorbar is a rainbow colormap (somehow), which is not very helpful.  Instead I need two independent, custom colorbars.  What I would like is to have a vertical colorbar to the right that is black-white and scaled to the range of z, and a horizontal colorbar on the bottom that is blue-red and scaled to the range of w.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: There is one small error in my formula, it should read: (r,g,b) = (z'*w', 0, z'*(1-w')).

Comment: If I understand your question, then you are looking for something like http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/colorbar_only.html. Else put some sample code.

Comment: Yes that answers my question, thank you.  I scoured the matplotlib examples for quite awhile, I don't know how I missed that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As imsc pointed out in a comment to my question, the answer lies in the [matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/colorbar_only.html) he linked to.  Here is the code that I'm using, following the linked example, that solves the situation in my question specifically:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

ax_cb1 = fig.add_axes((0.85, 0.125, 0.03, 0.75))
BW_cdict = {
    'red':    ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
               (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
     'green': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
               (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
     'blue': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
               (1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
    }
black_white = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('BlackWhite', BW_cdict)
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=z_min, vmax=z_max)
cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(
    ax_cb1, cmap=black_white, norm=norm, orientation='vertical'
)

ax_cb2 = fig.add_axes((0.125, 0.95, 0.75, 0.03))
BR_cdict = {
    'red':    ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
               (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
     'green': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
               (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
     'blue':  ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
               (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    }
blue_red = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('BlueRed', BR_cdict)
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=w_min, vmax=w_max)
cb2 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(
    ax_cb2, cmap=blue_red, norm=norm, orientation='horizontal'
)
```